# Error de invalid syntax (from execute)

Tags: python, django

Estoy queriendo hacer funcionar este proyecto

https://github.com/createdbyfahad/django-react-example

en el que uno de los pasos (en el tercer paso) me sale error:

> How to run After cloning the repo, do the following to setup the app:
>   1- from the backend folder, execute those lines:

```
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py createsuperuser  (en este)
python manage.py runserver
```

obtengo este error

> python manage.py createsuperuser   File "manage.py", line 14
>       ) from exc
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

por que obtengo este error?

este es el archivo `manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero procura que tengas tu **entorno virtual creado y activado**:

Para crear el entorno:

```
python -m venv myvenv
```

Para activar el entorno, te diriges mediante la `CMD` a:

```
myvenv/Scripts/activate.ps1
```

---

**El error que obtienes es porque antes de crear un usuario se debe de correr el servidor es decir**:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Después de una vez iniciado el servidor, puedes crear un usuario, cuando usas solo `pip install django` puedes usar el siguiente comando sin problemas:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Pero cuando usas `pip3 install django`, **es necesario usar `python3`**, como a continuación:

```
python3 manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: obtengo este error  No module named venv

Comment: Hola he añadido algo a mi respuesta que había dejado por alto, debes de correr el servidor, antes de crear un usuario, mira de nuevo mi respuesta, disculpa mi error

Comment: obtengo este error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework, un favor puedes hacer correr ese proyecto en tu local, soy nuevo en python, te lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: pip3 install djangorestframework, debería de arreglarlo, eso instala el módulo que te salta el error

Comment: ahora me sale este error rest_framework_simplejwt

Comment: el proyecto tiene bastantes modulos adicionales que con pip install -r requirements.txt deberían de instalarse

Comment: pip install djangorestframework_simplejwt para el último error que te dió

Comment: me ayudas con mi nueva pregunta porfavor https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309137/error-al-instalar-un-proyecto-que-usa-pivenv